# Sound issues on RaspberryPi 4

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, headphones, raspberrypi

Just to see if a Raspberry Pi4+4G was good enough to swap out as my primary desktop, I decided to give it a try. I grabbed the [64 bit image for 20.04](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) for the Pi4, dumped it to an SD card, installed LXQT (my preferred desktop), spent like an hour reading through [the raspberry pi docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md) (plus many reboots) trying to get both my monitors to show the right resolution, was very pleased that most of my daily applications are install-able and usuable, AND I even got an external SSD mounting on boot for my /home!

Done. Let's relax by watching a video...Plays smooth which is a plus. But no sound...

Now I'm nearly three hours in on just sound and I've never hated HDMI more than I do now. I just want sound out of my headphone jack, yet I can NOT seem to get HDMI audio disabled...Why disable HDMI audio?

1. My dual monitors are nice 1080p monitors that I quite like. However, my old system was built around DisplayPort...not HDMI...fortunately one has a DVI (the primary 0) and the other has an HDMI port as well. I got cables for each to the RPi4 micro-HDMI and both now work at the correct resolution. But - this is important - neither have sound.
2. I'm on my headphones most of the day anyway, so I don't need anything fancy. Even if my monitors suddenly sprouted speakers, they wouldn't have a headphone jack.

I've been trying /everything/ I can find. Tried disabling pulseaudio and forcing alsa. Then I re-enabled pulse, made LOADS of changes and tweaks and deleted my ~/.pulse countless times. I've thrown all kinds of options into my /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt. But I just can't get audio out of the headphone jack.

So, here's what I've got right now for my /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt:

```
# Most of the settings weren't working for both monitors until I explicitly set it for both
disable_overscan:0=1
disable_overscan:1=1
hdmi_group:0=1
hdmi_group:1=1
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2
gpu_mem=256
hdmi_mode:0=16
hdmi_mode:1=16
#Sound
hdmi_drive=1 # Force DVI (no audio)
hdmi_drive:0=1 # Force DVI (no audio) for display 0
hdmi_drive:1=1 # Force DVI (no audio) for display 1
hdmi_ignore_edid_audio=1
hdmi_ignore_edid_audio:0=1
hdmi_ignore_edid_audio:1=1
hdmi_force_edid_audio=0
hdmi_force_edid_audio:0=0
hdmi_force_edid_audio:1=0
dtparam=audio=on
```

For PulseAudio, these are the most changes to /etc/pulse/default.pa :

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0

# This next one doesn't matter, the headphone option moves around.
# If I'm lucky on reboot to land on this option matching the headphones, it still does nothing
# set-default-sink alsa_card.platform-bcm2835_audio.2
```

When I open the PulseAudio Mixer GUI, I can see three devices (and no, none of them are muted). VLC is playing and the blue bar bounces back and forth, but no audible sound. If I disable the HDMI, the blue bar stops being show. If I force the headphone jack, the blue bar stops being shown. I can switch between the two HDMI's and the blue bar will continue to bounce, but the moment I try to mute them or force the headphones, the blue bar stops moving. All of that indicates to me that it can't play sound via the headphone jack.

Now for the kicker. Unplug the monitors and reboot. Log in remotely via SSH and pipe sound `sudo play  -n synth 14:30:00 brown` ... it works! GAH!!!! [explicative deleted] HDMI!!! Plug in monitors and reboot...no sound...GAH!!!!

So...I'm really frustrated and could just use another pair of eyes on what I've done wrong. Nearly everything else about the Pi seems to work great for me so far (just a bit more screen tear than I like, but that's a meh). But I do kinda need sound...

Can anyone help please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I put this

```
SUBSYSTEM!="sound*", GOTO="end"
ACTION!="change", GOTO="end"
KERNEL!="card*", GOTO="end"

# remove the 'internal' sound form factor, so more descriptive
# names are used in pulseaudio for bcm... entries
ENV{SOUND_FORM_FACTOR}=="internal", ENV{SOUND_FORM_FACTOR}=""

# uncomment to ignore audio sink on HDMI1, even if present, so that
# headphones + HDMI0 audio will work in pulseaudio - temporary workaround
ATTRS{id}=="b2", ENV{PULSE_IGNORE}="1"

LABEL="end"
```

into /lib/udev/rules.d/79-rpi-pulseaudio-fixes.rules

and it solved my headphone jack audio problem.

## For further reading

https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/3-5mm-audio-output-not-working-on-rpi4-with-20-04/22456/5
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=275372&start=125

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem. Don't use a 64bit OS on the RPi4 right now.

I tore in as deep as I could chasing down this issue. I found too many posts online saying to use the official Raspbian instead, so as a frustrated last resort I switched to Raspbian 32bit and it works. Tried the 64bit beta for Raspbian and it didn't work. Switch back to the 32 bit and it works.
The 64bit drivers apparently have a ways to go and I couldn't figure out where they broke. Someone with more knowledge than I will need to dig into it.

Unfortunately, I need 64bit for what I hoped to do. So I've decided to use the RPi4 for a different project all-together. Maybe I will circle back to this in the future and try again.